# How to allow popup in reactnative web view

Tags: react-native, webview, popup

In my app,
I need to allow popups in the web view itself.
now its try to redirect to the native browser when the popup comes.

I'm using (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) for web view.

current my code like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const URL="https://google.com";



export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: URL }}
        />
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 28,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Is there any way to enable popups?
appreciate your help. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically,
A Boolean value indicates whether JavaScript can open windows without user interaction. The default value is false.
You can set it as true. Then popups will allow.

```
<WebView
 javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically=true,
 source={{ uri: URL }}
  />
```